# Re-route dynamically for Camel Routes

Tags: java, jms, apache-camel

I am trying to figure out how to re-route dynamically for a camel route. I currently calculate the route in a processor based on some inputs. The route is then put into the message header. I thought I'd be able to re-route dynamically using

`.routingSlip(header("myHeader").toString())`

or something like it, but I have not had any luck so far.

Any help is appreciated...

Answer (score 2):

You should not use the .toString(), it should simply be

```
.routingSlip(header("myHeader"))
```

As documented in the Camel documentation
http://camel.apache.org/routing-slip

Then "myHeader" should just contain 1..n endpoints where the message should be routed. If you have multiple endpoints then separate them with comma.

Comment: When I didn't add toString() I got an error about routingSlip not working with a ValueBuilder.

Comment: What version of Camel are you using? Could be an older release. As routing slip uses a header by default, you ought be able to do just: .routingSlip("myHeader"). eg pass in a String which is the header name.

Answer (score 1):

We, during our processor, set a property:

```
exchange.setProperty("sendTo", blah);
```

then, instead of `routingSlip`, use `recipientList` like:

```
.recipientList(property("sendTo"));
```

...which works great.  I don't think a full example is necessary for this?

Comment: This is what I ended up having to do as well. I can use the header notation to get it off the message instead of the exchange though.